# Need help putting the else into the while with a counter

Tags: python, if-statement

```
password = str()

while password != "changeme":
    password = input("Password: ")
print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
else print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
```

Could I please have some helo with my code.

I want it to print "Though Shall Not Pass Into Mordor" when the password is incorrect 5 times. Can someone please help me! Can someone also please put a counter in?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `break` to end a loop, and use `for` with a `range()`:

```
for attempt in range(5):
    password = input("Password: ")
    if password == "changeme":
        print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
        break
else:
    print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
```

The `else` branch of a `for` loop is **only** executed when you did not use `break` to end the loop.

Demo:

```
>>> # Five failed attempts
...
>>> for attempt in range(5):
...     password = input("Password: ")
...     if password == "changeme":
...         print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
...         break
... else:
...     print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
... 
Password: You shall not pass!
Password: One doesn't simply walk into Mordor!
Password: That sword was broken!
Password: It has been remade!
Password: <whispered> Toss me!
Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor
>>> # Successful attempt after one failure
...
>>> for attempt in range(5):
...     password = input("Password: ")
...     if password == "changeme":
...         print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
...         break
... else:
...     print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
... 
Password: They come in pints?! I'm having one!
Password: changeme
Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor
```

Comment: You should change `input` to `raw_input`.  `input` will try to evaluate whatever the input is, but `raw_input` will simply make it a string. In this case, you want `raw_input`.

Comment: @KyleNeary the OP is using python 3.

Comment: @KyleNeary: I already commented about this on your now-deleted answer. `raw_input` is gone in Python 3, it has been renamed to `input()`, and the old `input()` from Python 2 is gone.

Comment: @Martijn: I deleted my answer because yours answered the question so much better.  Thanks for the correction!