# How do I display the count in the Password:

Tags: python

```
for attempt in range(5):                        
    password = input("Password: ")              
    if password == "changeme":
        print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
        break
else:
    print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
```

I need help so it displays the tries into password like this:

> Password(1 attempts):

Comment: It seems like an odd question. You have most, if not all of the logic already worked out, what's exactly not working?

Comment: Please, don't just ask bit by bit.. we know you asked for something else a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20479259/need-help-putting-the-else-into-the-while-with-a-counter

Comment: I think user wants to display the number of false tries

Comment: No, it seems user wants his or her homework done bit by bit without putting any effort. Check his previous questions.

Comment: Sorry, Im new to StackOverflow and not too sure how it works

Comment: People want to help, but they won't do your work for you.  To write a good question, describe specifically what you're hoping to do, what you've done so far, and how your results are different from what you are expecting.  If there's something specific you don't understand, ask.  Good grammar and spelling are also bonuses, although we know English isn't everybody's first language.  Basically, you want to show that you've done some effort and tried on your own.  Not only will this keep people happy with you, but it's better for your own development in the long run.

Answer (score 3):

Your `attempt` variable holds the number of tries. Concatenate that with a print statement in your for loop.

**Edit:** Deleted Add 1, it is not necessary.

Comment: You should've let the OP figure this out by him/herself.. this problem was not too hard.

Comment: Good answer (helpful, but not giving solution for free). Adding 1 is not required though to display "attempts so far", and I guess that's the goal.

Answer (score 0):

```
password_attempt = 0
for attempt in range(5):                        
    password = input("Password: ")              
    if password == "changeme":
        print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
        break
else:
    password_attempt += 1
    print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
    print(Password(%s attempt(s)) %password_attempt
```

Answer (score 0):

I just made a little change to the code you posted to match yours needs.

```
for attempt in range(1, 5):                                # Change range to be 1 - 5.
    password = input("Password (%d attempts): " % attempt) # Change input message showing attempt number.             
    if password == "changeme":
        print("Thou Shall Pass Into Mordor")
        break
else:
    print("Thou Shall Not Pass Into Mordor")
```